# systemd service: StandardError writes to StandardOutput

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I’m on Debian 9 with systemd 236 (via backports, in order to use file:) and I have the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=landing

[Service]
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant

WorkingDirectory=/srv/landing/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node app.js
StandardOutput=file:/srv/landing/logs/app/stdout
StandardError=file:/srv/landing/logs/app/stderr

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target srv-landing-app.mount
```

The problem is that stderr goes to /srv/landing/logs/app/**stdout** instead of /srv/landing/logs/app/**stderr**.

When I run my app with `./app.js 2> err 1> out` stderr and stdout are separated correctly, so the mistake isn’t from the app.

I’d very much like to know what is going on there.

*Edit:* Output of a shell script that does `ls -l /proc/$$/fd; exit 0` in ExecStart as requested in the comments:

```
total 0
lr-x------ 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Jan 17 21:59 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Jan 17 21:59 1 -> /srv/landing/logs/app/stdout
lr-x------ 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Jan 17 21:59 10 -> /home/vagrant/x.sh
l-wx------ 1 vagrant vagrant 64 Jan 17 21:59 2 -> /srv/landing/logs/app/stdout
```

*Edit 2:* I tried a service file with only StandardError — without StandardOutput — and StandardError works correctly in that case.

(I also tried swapping the order of StandardError and StandardOutput, but this doesn’t change anything.)

Comment: That's bizarre. Could you replace the ExecStart entry so that it runs a shell script that does `ls -l /proc/$$/fd; exit 0` and show us the output?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Done.

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but just to make sure - did you do a systemd reload after updating the unit file?
Otherwise it sounds like a systemd bug :(
It looks like StandardError is completely ignored, and falls back to the default `inherit` behaviour as described at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardError=

Comment: @viraptor I did. It indeed behaves the same as `inherit` (just tested it). I’m also pretty sure it’s a bug at this point (see my second edit).

Comment: for some reason the process creates file descriptor 2 as a symlink to the stdout file. Could be a bug on that process.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10875 - Redirect StandardError to a file doesn't work if StandardOutput is set